# How do I test conditional behaviour with Behat/Mink?

Tags: php, behat, mink, gherkin

I have a condition I'd like to test in my Behat scenario but I can't think how it should be described.

I am testing a webpage displaying articles - if there is one sponsored article then there should be two featured articles, if there is no sponsored article then there should be three feature articles.

How do I approach this in Gherkin? If I do, say, `Given there is one sponsored article` then as soon as there is no sponsored article, that test will fail.

Is this beyond the scope of the tool? If so how would I go about testing this scenario?

Comment: Depends on how the code of sponsored article looks like. If a number or flag is the trigger, you need to let one of the describing strings inject that value like: Given there is "1" sponsored article

Comment: @SenseException How do you mean, inject the value? Could you give an example? Cheers

Comment: I have, for now, used the following language:
`Scenario: Sponsored article\n Given There may be a "#deal-item" element\n Then the "#featured-items" csselement should contain 3 "article" elements, less the number of "#deal-item" elements` this seems sufficient for now, but I'm still not sure of the correct 'BDD' way to test this condition. Would a more suitable approach to be to get the test to modify the data to a known state beforehand?

Comment: Your scenario is not written correctly from a "BDD way" perspective. You're not writing acceptance tests, but functional tests. Start there before you get into secondary things, like when to create fixtures. I recommend reading "Specification by example".

Comment: @JakubZalas so I can't test this at all with BDD? I don't quite follow - what/where/when is the best way to handle this test scenario?

Comment: Just because you use a tool created for BDD, doesn't mean you follow the practice. I can tell you did not write those scenarios with your business, as they're not written in a business language. I just don't want you to call it BDD, while what you do is functional testing. I gave you an answer regarding the fixtures.

Comment: @JakubZalas Can you expand on your answer regarding fixtures? I don't really understand what you mean. You keep saying this isn't BDD but I don't understand what it is supposed to be. The business has decided that if there is a sponsored article, there should be two featured articles; and if there is no sponsored article then there should be three featured articles. How is that not a business requirement?

Comment: It is a business requirement. You did not write it down as one - clients don't talk about css elements on the page ;) About fixtures - what exactly you'd like me to expand on?

Comment: The answer you gave below is spot on I think, so thank you for that :) It's odd that Behat/Mink allows the use of CSS selectors if their use then breaks the BDD nature of the tests...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scenarios should be deterministic. This means that if you rely on a data from a database, it needs to be deterministic as well.

You can achieve it in multiple ways.

One way is to pre-populate your database with known data, either before the tests run or  before each scenario. Some of the data will be build during the scenario is run. This might be expensive, but most reliable.

Another way is to maintain database with fixtures for testing. The test suite will be quicker this way, but you have to be careful with changes you make during the test execution.

Which way is better to choose depends on which compromises you're willing to make.

You'll probably want to prepare at least two scenario to cover the edge cases:

```
Scenario: One sponsored article

Scenario: No sponsored articles
```

Unless you can visit two distinct pages to reproduce both scenarios, you'll have to pre-populate (or update) the database before each one of them.

In your step:

```
Given there is one sponsored article
```

you should either create a sponsored article (if you're populating the database for each scenario), or verify it exists (if you rely on a pre-populated database).

Comment: Just to help and complete this answer, a way of making these deterministic scenarios without coping-pasting is by using place holders in scenarios. More info here: http://behat.org/en/latest/user_guide/writing_scenarios.html#scenario-outlines